# How to download a folder on dropbox as a zip file and save it locally?

Tags: python, keras, raspberry-pi3, dropbox-api

I'm progressively adding images to a dropbox folder remotely which I then need to download on my raspberry pi 3.

The thing is I only need the latest uploaded image in that folder so that I can classify it remotely using some code deployed on my raspberry pi 3.

I don't know the dropbox api well so I don't know if there's any functionality to directly implement what I said above, so I'm trying to download the entire folder with all the images locally and then select the image that I want.

Dropbox api v2 says they added functionality to download entire folders as zip files but whenever I try to implement the code given in the api and save the file locally, the local zip files always says it's corrupt and can't be opened.

Does anyone know how this can be implemented in python ?

Edit: Or maybe shed light if there's a simpler way to download the latest uploaded image to a folder without explicitly changing the code with that specific image's name or link ?

Comment: Not a code writing service.  You'll need to try first, post what you did and ask for help troubleshooting particular problems.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download_zip

Start by getting the download working in a Linux terminal using CURL, then you can work your way up by making the HTTP request using Python Requests library.  That way you can debug it systematically.  Make sure there aren't any issues with file permissions on Dropbox or API tokens.

Comment: I was able to download it using the Python requests library but when I try to save it locally as a zip file, it always says zipp file is corrupt and can't be opened. I can save jpegs and txt files in the same way but when its a zip file it never opens. Is there something different we have to do when saving zip files ?